# SAS: How to numerically recover a parameter from an equation involving integration?

Tags: sas

I aim to find a (alpha) that satisfies the below equation, where F and p are given

[image]

To give a concrete example, suppose we aim to find alpha that satisfies the below given constants p, l, and u:

[image]

How do I do it in SAS? I am open to solutions in `proc IML` or any other package. But bonus points for using a solution that doesn't involve `SAS/OR` as that is not available to me.

I am really struggling to come up with a MWE (apart from writing out a long 200-line solution using macros) but from my research I think `proc nlin` seem promising, but I think the examples in the doc all optimize a target and the RHS (explanatory data) provided that they sit on the data-row. There is no example where we aggregate the data-rows (to simulate integration) and then recover the parameter(s).

This can be solved using a one-liner in R (most of the time), plus the code needed to define the function `F`, and the sum of squares of the difference between `p` and the integral (which is around 50 lines in my case with comments).

```
optim(init_params, F)
```

so I think there is a solution in SAS that is sub 10 lines long.

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2014/08/06/objective-function-that-evaluates-integral.html

Comment: Looks promising. Will try once I get back to work